# React MUI [FilledInput] doesn't capture last the character

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state

I'm using MUI Input Adornments to enable 'show / hide password' and React State to keep the final password (in order to pass it via the login).

For some reason, latest character is missing, below is a code that show the idea:
(link: https://codesandbox.io/s/passwordwithshow-c3ktnj?file=/src/App.js:0-1894)

```
export default function InputAdornments() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    password: "",
    showPassword: false
  });

  const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    console.log(values.password);
  };

  const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      showPassword: !values.showPassword
    });
  };

  const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: "30ch" }} variant="filled">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-adornment- password">Password</InputLabel>
        <FilledInput
          id="filled-adornment-password"
          type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange("password")}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <IconButton
                aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                edge="start"
              >
                {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
        />
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the console, 'I' is missing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your code, So basically what happening is when the onChange event fires it updates the **state** with the target value and when you're console logging the **state** inside your **onChange** handler, it will log the **prevState** coz the current state is not updated yet in the states.

so if you want to use the value inside the onChange you should use the event.target.value instead of state.

```
console.log(password) => console.log(event.target.value)
```

Comment: Yes, alternatively move the `console.log(values.password)` up one level (out of the `handleChange` function.